# Angular 8 RXJS6 Observable pre-process response before return

Tags: angular, rxjs, observable, angular2-observables, rxjs-observables

I have an observable that makes an API call. The API call returns an array of objects in the response.

I am using this observable in multiple places. In most cases, I want the object in the response.

However, in the case of CanDeactivate, I need to 'pre-process' the response to return true or false instead, since CanDeactivate is expected to return Observable.

Is there a way to tap into the response to process it ahead of time (perhaps using the 'tap' operation?)

```
  canDeactivate(): Observable<boolean> | boolean {

    // Check if Is Being Edited must be removed
    if (this.mustReleaseIsBeingEdited()) {
      return this.updateIsBeingEdited$(false);
    } else {
      return of(true);
    }

  }

  public updateIsBeingEdited$(_id: string, IsBeingEdited: boolean): Observable<Record[]> {

    return this.httpService!.postData(
      `records/_id/${_id}/IsBeingEdited/${IsBeingEdited}`,
      {}
    );

  }
```

Comment: Use pipe with [map](https://www.learnrxjs.io/operators/transformation/map.html)

Comment: `return this.updateIsBeingEdited$(false).map(resp => { // process as per your need });

Comment: Thanks! I am getting the error message: TS2339: Property 'map' does not exist on type 'Observable<boolean>'

Comment: Also tried this: `return this.updateIsBeingEdited$(false)
        .pipe(
          map(result => {
            return true
          }),
          catchError(e => console.error(e))
        );`

but getting this error: TS2322: Type 'void' is not assignable to type 'ObservableInput<any>

Comment: in `catchError` you have to return an Observable. `return Observable.throw(e);`. Or if you don't care about it, just remove the `catchError` part

Comment: Thanks very much! This seems to be working:       return this.updateIsBeingEdited$(false)
        .pipe(
          map(result => {
            // Always allow deactivation
            return true
          }),
          catchError(e => {
            console.error(e);
            return Observable.throw(e);
          })
        );